# Are Coq tacticals right associative or left associative?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, logical-foundations

I was going through [software foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Imp.html) and got the example:

```
repeat (try (left; reflexivity); right).
```

and was confused what this meant. For example do we get:

```
try [ (left; reflexivity); right ]
```

or

```
[try (left; reflexivity);] right
```

second or first?

---

in particular I was trying to understand:

```
Theorem In10 : In 10 [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10].
Proof.
  repeat (try (left; reflexivity); right).
Qed.
```

Comment: what is the best way to find out what left/right tactics mean? I saw the official docs but didn't make sense...

Comment: Re "I saw the official docs but didn't make sense" If there's a particular part of it that is confusing or nonsensical, please open an issue on github (https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/new) with specific requests for clearer documentation

Answer (score 3):

A good way of solving those problems on your own is to use tactics like `idtac` (always succeeds) and `fail` (always fails) to disambiguate:

```
try (idtac; idtac); fail.     (* FAILS *)
try ((idtac; idtac); fail).   (* SUCCEEDS *)
(try (idtac; idtac)); fail.   (* FAILS *)
```

So indeed, the application of `try` binds tighter than the semicolon:

```
try (idtac; idtac); fail.   is the same as   (try (idtac; idtac)); fail.
```

Comment: sorry I am new to coq, how do I search what `idtac` is/does?

Comment: does it bind tighter because its left associative in general? this was helpful for this particular example, but how do I know this in general?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the semicolon operator for tactics is associative, so `((a ; b); c)` is the same as `a ; (b ; c)`, and parentheses are unnecessary. However, your initial question had less to do with associativity, and more to do with the precedence of the `;` operator v.s. the ` ` operator. Whitespace binds tighter, so that `a b c ; d e f ; g h i` always means `(a b c) ; (d e f) ; (g h i)`.

Comment: @Ptival Whitespace does not always bind tighter.  See for example https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/5441 and also the `now` tactical.  See also https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/9447

Comment: @Pinocchio You can see the grammar for the tactic language at https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html .  You can see what `idtac` does at https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.idtac