# Can composing try and repeat lead to an infinite loop in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I know that repeat applies a tactical multiple times until it fails.

> The repeat tactical takes another tactic and keeps applying this tactic until it fails.

and the try tactic does nothing when it "fails":

> If T is a tactic, then try T is a tactic that is just like T except that, if T fails, try T successfully does nothing at all (instead of failing).

does that mean if I were to do something like:

```
repeat (try reflexivity).
```

if the reflexivity fails then try does nothing (but not fail) so repeat just keeps applying `try reflexivity`. Is this correct? Or what is going?

---

The reason I ask is because I saw this theorem:

```
Theorem In10 : In 10 [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10].
Proof.
  repeat (try (left; reflexivity); right).
Qed.
```

when I asked a related question: [Are Coq tacticals right associative or left associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750496/are-coq-tacticals-right-associative-or-left-associative)

source: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Imp.html

Comment: where is the definition of "progress"?

Answer (score 3):

The actual semantics of `repeat` are that it stops if the tactic fails to make progress.

https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html?highlight=repeat#coq:tacn.repeat

So a simple use of `repeat` and `try` will not create an infinite loop if no change happens to your goal, even though the tactic does succeed.

However, it is indeed possible to make `repeat` go in an infinite loop, as long as it makes progress at each iteration. For instance, the following script tries to build a list by always using the `cons` constructor, rather than finishing at some point with `nil`:

```
Theorem there_exists_a_list_of_nat : list nat.
Proof.
  repeat right.
```

It will indeed loop forever (make sure you know how to cancel a computation before you try and run it).

Comment: does that mean the website I cite is wrong with this claim: `(e.g., repeat simpl loops, since simpl always succeeds)`?

Comment: where is the definition of "progress"?

Comment: @Pinocchio [See the reference manual entry on `progress`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html?highlight=progress#coq:tacn.progress). To summarize, if a tactic produces a goal which is syntactically identical to the original goal, then it has failed to progress.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern does not lead to an infinite loop because repeat t stops when t fails to make progress, not when it fails. The documentation (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.repeat) adds this in a followup sentence, though it could certainly be clearer.

The additional explanation in Software Foundations is wrong; it claims repeat goes into an infinite loop when given a tactic that always succeeds, and gives repeat simpl as an example, but repeat simpl works (after at most one round of simpl it won’t do anything if run again so repeat stops).

Comment: where is the definition of "progress"?